# Static polymorphism and method names c++

Tags: c++, static-polymorphism

When I use static polymorphism (CRTP), is there a nice way to give polymorphic methods their names?

```
template <class Derived> 
struct Base
{
    void interface()
    {
        // ...
        static_cast<Derived*>(this)->implementation();
        // ...
    }

    static void static_func()
    {
        // ...
        Derived::static_sub_func();
        // ...
    }
};

struct Derived : Base<Derived>
{
    void implementation();
    static void static_sub_func();
};
```

Because, as far as I know, interface and implementation can't have the same name (as they would if they were virtual). And that's kinda awkward, if class hierarchy is deep.

Maybe there is some nice way to deal with it? Or maybe I'm just wrong?

Comment: Why should it be impossible to have the same name in interface (actually base class) and implementation (actually derived class)?

Comment: I think what's the `virtual` keyword is for.

Comment: @georgesl When you're doing CRTP, you're doing it to *avoid* `virtual` functions.

Comment: interface and implementation CAN have the same name.  They dont need to be virtual because it is resolved at compile time.  implementation() in the derived class would hide the implementation in 'base'.  The static cast to Derived causes the Derived version of the function to be called.

Comment: @Pete: While they can have the same name, it's not a good idea. The intention is that `derived.interface()` calls the base version, which in turn calls the derived version; if they have the same name, then that would call the derived version directly.

Comment: For some reason, I thought that there will be recursion (probably some stupid mistake). Anyway, are there some naming rules, maybe?

Comment: Some (dare I say many) commercial template libraries exploit the hell out of this capability. (ATL for example).

Comment: @Mike Seymour - it depends on what you are trying to achieve.  If you want to effectively emulate virtual functions for use in a TMP environment then using the same name can be very useful.  i.e. Base may call a function that could be overidden in 'Derived' but have a default implementation in 'Base' that is called if 'Derived' did not override it.  You can always call the base method via Base::interface(...).  In all cases calling any function from within Base should cast 'this' to 'Derived'.  It is nice to have: Derived* This() { return static_cast<Derived*>(this); } to keep code clean.

Answer (score 2):

My approach would be to avoid inheritance (however cute CRTP feels), and use aggregation instead. A class template provides the interface, and is in turn provided a delegate class with the implementation. It would look something like this:

```
template <class Delegate>
struct Interface
{
    void do_something()
    {
        // ...
        delegate.do_something();
        // ...
    }

    Delegate delegate;
};
```

This has the disadvantage that it's more awkward to supply constructor arguments to the delegate object, but that's not too difficult to manage.

Comment: And what are the benefits of this?

Comment: 1. It allows you to give the function the same name in the interface and implementation (as you requested). 2. The class relationships are simpler. 3. The code is cleaner, with no need for casting. 4. It doesn't couple the implementation to the interface, so any delegate classes you define can be used independently of the interface class.

Answer (score 0):

When the parent class doesn't have any special functionality (as in a typical abstract interface), I can't see a reason why you can't reuse the function name in the child class. It will hide the parent method, but that doesn't matter because you're statically telling the compiler which version you wish to use.

However in your case it *appears* that you want the parent to do some work before and after calling the virtual method (smells like Template Method Pattern). In this case, regardless of whether you use runtime (virtual) or compile time (CRTP) polymorphism, you'll need to call your interface and implementation methods by alternate names.

If `foo` is the interface/template method in the base, then `do_foo` or `foo_impl` seem like perfectly reasonable names for the implementation functions regardless of runtime or compile time polymorphism.